# SQL Server : one stored procedure used in many databases

Tags: sql-server

I have one main database and I need to replicate it for each client (each client must have one separated database with its own information based on main database).

What is your suggestion to avoid the replication of stored procedures, triggers, functions etc and to have only one code in the main database? But using those procedures, triggers, functions, etc in each database of course.

Thanks and regards.

Comment: I suspect you have an XY problem. look up how to deploy database changes, DbUp for instance.

Comment: Agreed. Database migrations are the right solution to this problem.

Comment: Likely what the other guys said is true in your case, but fyi you can make cross-database calls in SQL Server, so if your database code is truly generic, it can all live in a single *utilities* type of database that is used against or references from the other databases.